# Creating Form in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to create a form for editing attributes in QGIS. I have a lot of question and hope somebody can suggest how they work or where I can read about the next elements of form:

1. Classification
2. List
3. Relation References (I have found some information about this one. http://blog.vitu.ch/10112013-1201/qgis-relations, but it doesn't activate)

Comment: related, covers classification: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30045/looking-for-an-explanation-of-qgis-edit-widgets