# Creating Dropdown list in QGIS Print Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts, dropdownlist

I´m trying to find a way to create a dropdown list in the QGIS Print composer. I know that there´s a way to do it in the attributes tables but what I´m looking for is to have the same result in the print composer itens. For more info about the dropdown list I´ve separated this link:

1 - [How to create a drop down list?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29858/how-to-create-a-drop-down-list)

[image]

During my search I saw many pages like this:

2 - [Creating multiple select dropdown list in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306881/creating-a-multiple-select-dropdown-list-in-qgis)

3 - [Creating a dropdown list to select by different attributes in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396077/creating-a-dropdown-list-to-select-by-different-attributes-in-qgis)

4 - https://youtu.be/CVhBMWReYZM

I´m expecting to see this in the print composer instead of Canvas:

[image]

How can I create the dropdown list? I´m using QGIS version 3.18

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of an example what you're aiming to achieve?